# Prevent further looping and Add the remaining fields depending on count in MVC 5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, indexing, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I'm just having a problem in MVC 5 where I need to pass a value on the first Loop and leave it empty on the remaining loops depending on the number of Count still remains (Sorry having hard time explaining it in technical terms)

Here is my Set of Codes:

In my Model :

```
public class EventAttendeeViewModel
    {
 public IList<getAttendeeList> getAttendeeLists {get;set;}
    }
    public class getAttendeeList
    {
        public virtual int? AttendeeTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name", Prompt = "Attendee Last Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name", Prompt = "Attendee First Name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "PhoneNumber is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Cell Phone")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
}
```

in my Controller

```
eventattendee.AdultCount = model.AdultCount;
eventattendee.AttendeeCount = model.eventattendee();
var listOfAttndees = new List<getAttendeeList>();
                var lstAttendees = new getAttendeeList();
                lstAttendees .FirstName = userInfo.FirstName;
                lstAttendees .LastName = userInfo.LastName;  
                lstAttendees .CellPhone = Helpers.CommonUtils.RemovePhoneFormat(phoneDetail.PhoneNumber);
                lstAttendees .Email = userInfo.EmailAddress;
                listOfAttndees .Add(lstAttendees );

                eventattendee.getAttendeeLists = listOfAttndees;
```

return View(eventAttendee);

and in my View

```
 @if (Model.AttendeeCount > 0 && Model != null)
                            {

                                for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdultCount; i++)
                                {

                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.isAdult)
                                    <div id="div_@i">
                                        <h2>Adult @(i + 1) </h2>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].CellPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].CellPhone, new { @class = "form-control PhoneMask" })
                                                </div>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].CellPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.getAttendeeLists[i].Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                }
```

Everytime I debug it triggers a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index` on the Second for loop of Model.AdultCount

Comment: How many times do I need to tell you this. Do **NOT** use `for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdultCount; i++)` In the GET method, if the value of `AdultCount` is say 3, then you add 3 instances of `getAttendeeList` to the collection, and then you use `for(int i = 0; i < Model.getAttendeeLists.Count; i++)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes sir i need 3 instances if the AdultCount says 3. I need to show 3 ticket forms for Adult if the count says 3 and get their name and phone

Comment: `getAttendeeLists` entries should be created in controller side depending on `AdultCount` value, not by using `AdultCount` in the loop inside view. Then, `getAttendeeLists.Count` will set to desired amount of `List<getAttendeeList>` entries when passed to view.

Comment: Then populate the `getAttendeeLists` with 3 instance of `getAttendeeList`. You currently only add one. So in the 2nd iteration of the loop you are creating inputs for the 2nd item in the collection - but there currently is no 2nd item (hence the error). And you need to get rid of those awful class names

Comment: `class getAttendeeList` should be `class Attendee` and the property should be `IList<Attendee> Attendees`